# How to create nested JSON for the multi-level menu list using Spring boot and MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, json, spring-boot, jpa, orm

I've been trying to create a multi-level nested JSON using MySQL and Spring boot.

I will need this JSON so I can later on use jQuery to create HTML menu.

But I'm currently struggling to create my multi-level nested JSON.

Basically, I've got an MYSQL database that looks like this:

```
id    categoryItem    parrent

1     car               0
2     red car           1
3     blue car          1
4     bike              0
5     yellow bike       4
```

The column post_parent is the column that links them together.

I've tried using the following Spring boot code but the JSON output is wrong.

My Entity class like that:

```
@Table(name = "category_item")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class CategoryItem implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "fa_icon")
    private String faIcon;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("categoryItems")
    private CategoryItem parrent;
}
```

I will need a multi-level nested JSON like this structure:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "car",
  "categoryItem": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "red car"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "blue car"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I handle it!? please help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it a bidrectional relationship:

```
@Table(name = "category_item")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class CategoryItem implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "fa_icon")
    private String faIcon;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private Set<CategoryItem> categoryItems;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("categoryItems")
    private CategoryItem parent;
}
```

Comment: I've tried but it does not work. A lot of people suggest using DTO. but I'm new with that. how to handle it with DTO?

Comment: You will need to expand on "I've tried but it does not work." if you want an answer.